# Device is not getting detected in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, device

Not able to detect device in Android Studio:

[image]

**Debugging is enabled:**
[image]

Comment: Are you using data cable to connect your device?

Comment: which device model ?

Comment: Either problem with cable or with driver

Comment: Is it not connecting at all? I mean are you fetting USB options on your device?

Comment: try `adb kill-server; adb start-server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found the issue was .... `ADB`file will gets deleted after some time ..... so un-installed avast antivirus and this resolved it

Answer (score 2):

Try below if it is not a problem with cable or with driver.

Open task manager of your system OS and kill adb.exe process. Now start adb again, it should start normally.

Answer (score 0):

You have a notification from Android System, click on it.
At the window that opened change USB connection 
from

> File transfer

to

> Photo transfer

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined **sdk path** to android studio ?

go through below path in Android studio settings and check **Android SDK Location**:

`Appearance & Behavior / System Settings / Android SDK`

Also adb.exe must be present in:

`YourSDKDrive:\....\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`

Note:

Try to update Android SDK Platform-Tools (28.0.2) if you already haven't. that might help

Answer (score -1):

please try Invalid Cached/Files